# How to draw this Arrow

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I can't seem to figure out how to draw the arrow shone (light red).  Is there a simple code? I know I am missing something. I scanned the Tikz and PGF plots manual and googled it. I can't seem to find it.

Any help is would be appreciated.

Nick[image]

Comment: [Shape `single arrow`.](https://tikz.dev/library-shapes#pgf.single:arrow)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Qrrbrbirlbel said in comment: you can draw this arrow as Ti*k*Z `single arrow` shape:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}

\begin{document}
\[
\int 4x^3\sqrt{x^4-6}\,dx = \int \sqrt{x^4-6}4x^3\,dx
\quad\tikz[baseline=-1ex]\node[single arrow, single arrow head extend=1.5mm, 
                               draw, fill=red!30, minimum height=9mm, right] {};\quad
\int \sqrt{u}\,du = \frac{2}{3}u^{3/2} + C = \frac{2}{3}(x^4-6)^{2/3}+C
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for taking time to look at this!

Answer (score 3):

As there is no `MWE`, have provided the code for creating the arrow only by using `PSTricks`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\begin{document}

  \psBigArrow[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue!30,doublesep=10pt,
          linecolor=blue,linewidth=1pt](-1,1)(1,1)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Better to use `LaTeX->dvips->Ps2PDF` for viewing purpose

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the comments. I know I did not have a MWE, my apologies. I took @Qrrbrbirlbel advice and tried some things from the link he provided.  Here is what I came up with:

```
\begin{scope}[shift={(9.75,16.5)},every node/.style={single arrow, draw,minimum height=1.5cm,single arrow head indent=2cm,minimum width=6ex}]
 \node [fill=red!15,single arrow head indent=.05ex] at (0,0){};
\end{scope}
```